# A web server to store files with unlimited bandwith

Tags: php, unity-game-engine, webserver, server, dropbox

I've recently started an android app (using Unity) and users will need to upload a (~200kb) file somewhere, and have another user download it later. I was planning to use Dropbox as they have a 20gb daily bandwith allowance, but I can't find a way to upload files to my dropbox account through code. Is there a way to upload to a dropbox account using C#?

I know it's possible using PHP, and I could have the user upload to a web server and then send it to a public dropbox folder. Though all the web servers I have found do not allow file storage/sending like that.

So also, what web servers do popular apps use to store all their data and have enough bandwith? If my app did become popular, I can't find a web server to handle thousands or more of concurrent users downloading and uploading.

Comment: search google for 'dropbox api' and you will get the gory details of the web services. AFAIK web services can be implemented with Csharp.

Comment: You will need to have some network storage. That is accessible to preferably only server, or if that is not possible the client. And upload to there. drobox is possible, but not good practice.

Comment: Thanks, I thought dropbox wouldn't be good practice, but I thought it would be a good way to start as I don't want to pay for storage when there might only be 10 app users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Dropbox Rest API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs)
and Unity's [WWW-Class](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html).

You should be able to consume the Dropboxapi via Unity.